# Управление формой с клавиатуры

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.x, форма

Задали задание, а толком с библиотекой не знаком. Вообщем нажимаем, допустим, клавишу "D" и после  отпускания  клавиши на клаве должна уменьшиться ширина формы.

Comment: @statkr, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Вы, скорее всего, меня неправильно поняли, я не прошу все сделать за меня. У меня Лаба из 20 заданий, все, что я не смог реализовать, задал 5 вопросов на хэш коде. Я лишь прошу показать реализацию отдельного действия, ибо я после прочитанной литературы не совсем или вовсе не понимаю реализацию того или иного действия, и предложенные мне решения далее использовать и опираясь на них искать аналогичные.

Comment: Можно разбить на несколько подзадач, чтобы освоиться с tkinter и если не ясно, как конкретный шаг выполнить, то задать *отдельный вопрос*:

1. Создаём форму и показываем её на экране.

2. Печатаем в консоль при нажатии на клавишу `D`.

3. Программно меняем размер формы.

4. Объединяем 2 и 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.
Управление положением формы через geometry.
Получение нажатой клавиши через bind и событие '<Key>', а дальше смотреть на event.keycode.